# Bind ng-options to nested array within JSON object, within ng-repeat

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ng-options

This is my first question, so please be gentle on me! I hope you can help.

I am trying to define a select box (dropdown) within my HTML view using ng-repeat, so that I can create a select for each item in an array. I have successfully achieved this, but my problems come when I try to get the options I need into each of the selects.

The array I am using`{
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": "Value01",
    "field3": "Value02",
    "refFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": 100,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueA"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": 101,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueB"
      }
    ]
  }, etc...`

I need a select per item in the 'top level' of the array, and in each select box the values that should appear should be the fieldValue from the refFields nested array.

My current (broken) code products some pretty rubbish results.
Here's the code:

```
<div ng-repeat="fk in fks">
        <ng-form name="fksForm">
            <select name="fkselect" ng-model="fk" ng-options="item as item.refFields for item in fks">                
            </select>
        </ng-form>
    </div>
```

Could anybody provide me with some insight into whether this is possible? I don't think that flattening the data is an option for this particular application. I've tried quite a few different things including passing an index to the ng-options, which as you might expect produced some pretty dodgy results. I also tried this, which doesn't give me any useful output.

```
ng-options="item as item.refFields.fieldValue for item in fks"
```

Here's my JSFiddle: [ng-option nested JSON Array within ng-repeat](https://jsfiddle.net/blackberry464/d50qq4c3/2/)

Many thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: It is unclear from your example how the values in retFields correspond to the values above, but I would suggest some preprocessing of the data in your controller into a more standard format and then it should be straight forward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [Underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) you could prepare your data for ng-options.

For me it looks pretty complicated. I would re-think if you could modify your data structure. I can't recommend a structure because I don't understand how the final result will look like.

I've created two arrays one with the field names that's used for the `ng-repeat` and the second array holds the `refFields` for the options.

With `$index` you can get the current index of the `ng-repeat` to access the `refFields`.

I'm not sure if I've created this correctly because I don't know what you're doing with the `field1`, `field2`, `field3` values.

Please have a look at this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/d50qq4c3/4/) or the demo below (same code).

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('DetailsCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
    var data = [
  {
    "field1": 1,
    "field2": "Value01",
    "field3": "Value02",
    "refFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": 100,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueA"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": 101,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueB"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "field1": 2,
    "field2": "Value03",
    "field3": "Value04",
    "refFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": 102,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueA"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": 103,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueB"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": 104,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueC"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": 105,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueD"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "field1": 3,
    "field2": "Value05",
    "field3": "Value06",
    "refFields": [
      {
        "fieldId": 106,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueA"
      },
      {
        "fieldId": 107,
        "fieldValue": "fieldValueB"
      }
    ]
  }
];
    $scope.fks = _.map(data, function(field) {
        return _.omit(field, ['field1', 'field2', 'field3']).refFields; // only refFields
    });
    console.log($scope.fks);
    $scope.fields = _.map(data, 
    function(field) {
        console.log(field);
        return [field.field1, field.field2, field.field3];
    }
    );
    //console.log(results)
    $scope.dropdown = {};
    
    $scope.changedValue = function(index) {
        console.log(index, $scope.dropdown);
        console.log($scope.dropdown[index]);
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.3/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="DetailsCtrl">
<form novalidate class="form-vertical" ng-show="!loading" name="detailsForm" ng-controller="DetailsCtrl">
    <!--<pre>{{fks |json}}</pre>-->
      <div ng-repeat="fk in fields">
          <ng-form name="fksForm">
              <label>{{fk}}</label>
                <select name="fkselect" ng-model="dropdown[$index]" ng-options="item.fieldValue for item in fks[$index]" ng-change="changedValue($index)">
                </select>
            </ng-form>
        </div>  
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this gave me what I needed to get the nested values into the select boxes. I was unaware that I was able to use $index within the ng-options. I will also look into underscore.js in further detail for future use, however I will try where possible in future to bash up the data into a more standard sort of format.

Answer (score 0):

Your data is fine, and there is a simpler way: make use of that `fk` and get the `refFields` directly from that, so `ng-options="item as item.fieldValue for item in fk.refFields"`.

For the full code:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="fk in fks">
        <label>{{fk.field2}}</label>
        <select ng-model="fk.selectedItem" ng-options="item as item.fieldValue for item in fk.refFields">              
        </select>      
    </div>  
</div>
```

And the data that you can just reference directly:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.controller('myCtrl',function($scope,$timeout) {
    $scope.fks = [
      {
        "field1": 1,
        "field2": "Value01",
        "field3": "Value02",
        "refFields": [
          { "fieldId": 100,  "fieldValue": "1fieldValueA" },
          { "fieldId": 101, "fieldValue": "1fieldValueB" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field1": 2,
        "field2": "Value03",
        "field3": "Value04",
        "refFields": [
          { "fieldId": 102, "fieldValue": "2fieldValueA" },
          { "fieldId": 103, "fieldValue": "2fieldValueB" },
          { "fieldId": 104, "fieldValue": "2fieldValueC" },
          { "fieldId": 105, "fieldValue": "2fieldValueD" }
        ]
      },
      {
        "field1": 3,
        "field2": "Value05",
        "field3": "Value06",
        "refFields": [
          { "fieldId": 106, "fieldValue": "3fieldValueA" },
          { "fieldId": 107, "fieldValue": "3fieldValueB" }
        ]
      }
    ];
});
```

And, of course, [the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80y3g8p9/1/).

Now just don't ask me how to initialise the select of a particular item in such lists: That's what I was here looking for.